# Describe what concavity means in terms if the location of the tangent relative to the function?

Tags: calculus

Describe what concavity means in terms if the location of the tangent relative to the function?

Does it tell us if the tangent is above the x-axis or not?
Like if the 1st derivative is positive, then the second derivative is above zero, meaning concave up and vice vera?

thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is concave up (what some books call "convex") then its graph lies on or above the graph of any one of its tangent lines.

Proof (assuming $f$ is twice differentiable): fix any real number $c$.  We want to show that the graph of $f$ lies on or above the graph of the tangent line to $f$ at $x = c$.

The tangent line to the graph of $f$ at $x = c$ has equation $y = f(c) + f'(c) (x - c)$, whereas the graph of $f$ has the equation $y = f(x)$.  Our claim, then, is that $f(x) \geq f(c) + f'(c) (x - c)$ holds for all $x$.  To simplify our discussion, let $h(x) = f(x) - f(c) - f'(c) (x - c)$.  In terms of $h$, our claim is that $h(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$.

Note that $h'(x) = f'(x) - f'(c)$ and that $h''(x) = f''(x)$.  Our hypothesis that $f$ is concave up implies that $h''(x) = f''(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$.  This means that $h'$ is nondecreasing for all $x$.  Note that $h'(c) = f'(c) - f'(c) = 0$.  Since $h'$ is nondecreasing, we deduce that $h'(x) \leq 0$ for all $x < c$ and that $h'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x > c$.  This means that $h$ is nonincreasing on $(-\infty, c)$ and that $h$ is nondecreasing on $(c, +\infty)$.  Note that $h(c) = f(c) - f(c) - f'(c) (0) = 0$.  Since $h$ is nonincreasing on $(-\infty, c)$ we deduce that $h(c) \geq 0$ for all $x < c$.  Since $h$ is nondecreasing on $(c, \infty)$ we deduce that $h(c) \geq 0$ for all $x > c$.  And clearly $h(c) = 0$.  We conclude that $h(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$.  End of proof.

Similarly, if $f$ is concave down then its graph lies on or below the graph of any one of its tangent lines.